# How to use an "any" type with JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema

I am looking at this:

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html

I have an object with a function property, but I don't want to set additionalProperties to true. So I want do something like:

```
      "properties": {
        "getHostNameSync": {
          "type": "any",   // << any
          "required": false
        }
      }
```

but it says my schema definition is invalid. Is there a way to include functions properties?

Comment: JSON schema cannot specify a function property - `JSON.stringify(() => {}) // => undefined`

Comment: JSON Schema is for validating JSON. How are you representing a function in JSON?

Comment: In my case I am using a library that's using JSON schema to validate a JS object

Comment: The library is very popular - AJV - https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Comment: @AlexanderMills why it looks like you have only 1 reputation??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With JSON Schema, you don't *have* to specify things.  The syntax is declarative and *adds* restrictions.  So if you don't want a restriction on the type of value that's allowed, don't use the `type` keyword.

```
  "properties": {
    "getHostNameSync": {}
  }
```

This will allow the `getHostNameSync` property to be literally anything since no restrictions have been declared.

***NOTE*** If you're using draft 6 or later, you can use `true` instead of `{}` and get the same effect.